# Bootstrapping dependency injection for a Xamarin Native to .NET project

Tags: xamarin, maui, .net-8.0

We have an existing Xamarin Native Android application that we are trying to migrate to a .NET project as documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/native-projects?view=net-maui-8.0

Historically, we have used a [TinyIoC](https://github.com/grumpydev/tinyioc) container for dependency injection but want to move to the standard/modern .NET dependency injection patterns. However, we are struggling to find the correct entry point to modify and to set the global/static instance of the container/service provider.

We've had a look at the MauiAppBuilder but that seemed to be more for "full" MAUI conversions (we have a lot of AXML view/activities etc. that we don't/can't rewrite for the purpose of this conversion).

We also had a look at changing the main Application inheritance from `Android.App.Application` to `Microsoft.Maui.MauiApplication` but that also didn't seem like the correct path (but would set the `IPlatformApplication` static value for us as we have used in MAUI first applications), and it felt like we were setting up to many "MAUI" items that didn't seem applicable when we're not using the MAUI UI?

We're now not sure what direction to take? Do we use a `ServiceHelper` class like suggested here? https://blog.ewers-peters.de/are-you-using-dependency-injection-in-your-net-maui-app-yet

We're wanting to minimise the custom code we need to add and are trying to reduce the custom orchestration in favour of solutions provided by .NET itself but the documentation to convert Xamarin Native applications is a little light on detail.